# How Jenkins can determine change in a specific folder for a GIT repo?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, webhooks

I have a Git Repo which has multiple folders. Each folder is a component of an application. We want to detect commits in a specific folder so that we can build individual component which had the latest commit. How can we achieve the same in Jenkins?

Ideally all of the components should be a specific repo, however, we don't have the flexibility to break from existing architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using git sparse checkout. Under advanced options of git of your job, you can specify what files/folders you want to checkout. [image: Git sparse checkout in Jenkins]

In addition, you also need to make sure your webhooks are set correctly, for automatic triggering of builds. which i assume you already have them configured.